# JOOQ statement with LATERAL not working (Postgresql)

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jooq

### The Problem

I am trying to convert the following SQL statement to JOOQ:

```
SELECT g.id, g.machine_id,
       xmin.min_trans_id,
       xmax.max_id
FROM   machine_location_move_events g
  , LATERAL 
       ( SELECT c.ts AS min_ts, c.id AS min_id, c.transaction_id AS min_trans_id
         FROM machine_economy_counters c
         WHERE c.move_event_id = g.id
           AND c.ts BETWEEN timestamp '2012-03-02 00:00:00'
                        AND timestamp '2014-03-05 12:00:00'
         ORDER BY c.ts ASC
         LIMIT 1
       ) xmin
  , LATERAL 
       ( SELECT c.ts AS max_ts, c.id AS max_id, c.transaction_id AS max_trans_id
         FROM machine_economy_counters c
         WHERE c.move_event_id = g.id
           AND c.ts BETWEEN timestamp '2012-03-02 00:00:00'
                        AND timestamp '2014-03-05 12:00:00'
         ORDER BY c.ts DESC 
         LIMIT 1
       ) xmax
WHERE xmin.min_ts IS NOT NULL ;
```

My JOOQ java code looks like this:

```
@Test
public void getTotalBetween() {
    DateTime from = new DateTime(2012, 3, 2, 0, 0, DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Copenhagen"));
    DateTime to = new DateTime(2014, 3, 5, 12, 0, DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Copenhagen"));

    DSLContext dslContext = jooqProvider.getDSLContext();

    SelectOffsetStep<Record3<Timestamp, Long, Long>> innerMinSelect;
    {
        MachineLocationMoveEvents gTable = MACHINE_LOCATION_MOVE_EVENTS.as("g");
        MachineEconomyCounters cTable = MACHINE_ECONOMY_COUNTERS.as("c");

        Field<Timestamp> min_ts = min(cTable.TS).as("min_ts");
        Field<Long> min_id = cTable.ID.as("min_id");
        Field<Long> min_transaction_id = cTable.TRANSACTION_ID.as("min_trans_id");

        innerMinSelect = dslContext.select(min_ts, min_id, min_transaction_id)
                  .from(cTable)
                  .where(cTable.MOVE_EVENT_ID.eq(gTable.ID)
                         .and(cTable.TS.between(new Timestamp(from.getMillis()), new Timestamp(to.getMillis()))))
                  .orderBy(cTable.TS.asc())
                  .limit(1)
                  ;
    }

    SelectOffsetStep<Record3<Timestamp, Long, Long>> innerMaxSelect;
    {
        MachineLocationMoveEvents gTable = MACHINE_LOCATION_MOVE_EVENTS.as("g");
        MachineEconomyCounters cTable = MACHINE_ECONOMY_COUNTERS.as("c");

        Field<Timestamp> max_ts = min(cTable.TS).as("max_ts");
        Field<Long> max_id = cTable.ID.as("max_id");
        Field<Long> max_transaction_id = cTable.TRANSACTION_ID.as("max_trans_id");

        innerMaxSelect = dslContext.select(max_ts, max_id, max_transaction_id)
                  .from(cTable)
                  .where(cTable.MOVE_EVENT_ID.eq(gTable.ID)
                         .and(cTable.TS.between(new Timestamp(from.getMillis()), new Timestamp(to.getMillis()))))
                  .orderBy(cTable.TS.desc())
                  .limit(1)
                  ;
    }

    MachineLocationMoveEvents gTable = MACHINE_LOCATION_MOVE_EVENTS.as("g");
    MachineEconomyCounters cTable = MACHINE_ECONOMY_COUNTERS.as("c");
    Field<Long> min_transaction_id = cTable.TRANSACTION_ID.as("min_trans_id");
    Field<Long> max_id = cTable.ID.as("max_id");
    Field<Timestamp> min_ts = min(cTable.TS).as("min_ts");

    Table<Record3<Timestamp, Long, Long>> minLateral = lateral(innerMinSelect).as("xmin");
    Table<Record3<Timestamp, Long, Long>> maxLateral = lateral(innerMaxSelect).as("xmax");

    SelectConditionStep<Record4<Integer, Integer, Long, Long>> minMaxSelect = dslContext.select(gTable.ID, gTable.MACHINE_ID, minLateral.field(min_transaction_id), maxLateral.field(max_id))
              .from(gTable, minLateral, maxLateral)
              .where(minLateral.field(min_ts).isNotNull());

    System.out.println(minMaxSelect.fetch());
}
```

I do however get this error message when I run the test: `ERROR: column "c.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

Full error:

```
org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: SQL [select "g"."id", "g"."machine_id", "xmin"."min_trans_id", "xmax"."max_id" from "public"."machine_location_move_events" as "g", lateral (select min("c"."ts") as "min_ts", "c"."id" as "min_id", "c"."transaction_id" as "min_trans_id" from "public"."machine_economy_counters" as "c" where ("c"."move_event_id" = "g"."id" and "c"."ts" between cast(? as timestamp) and cast(? as timestamp)) order by "c"."ts" asc limit ? offset ?) as "xmin", lateral (select min("c"."ts") as "max_ts", "c"."id" as "max_id", "c"."transaction_id" as "max_trans_id" from "public"."machine_economy_counters" as "c" where ("c"."move_event_id" = "g"."id" and "c"."ts" between cast(? as timestamp) and cast(? as timestamp)) order by "c"."ts" desc limit ? offset ?) as "xmax" where "xmin"."min_ts" is not null]; ERROR: column "c.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
  Position: 171
    at org.jooq.impl.Utils.translate(Utils.java:1287)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultExecuteContext.sqlException(DefaultExecuteContext.java:495)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:326)

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "c.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
  Position: 171
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2161)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1890)
```

The SQL from the error message looks like this when formatted nicely:

```
select "g"."id", "g"."machine_id",
       "xmin"."min_trans_id", 
       "xmax"."max_id" 
from "public"."machine_location_move_events" as "g"
  , lateral 
       ( select min("c"."ts") as "min_ts", "c"."id" as "min_id", "c"."transaction_id" as "min_trans_id" 
         from "public"."machine_economy_counters" as "c" 
         where ("c"."move_event_id" = "g"."id" 
           and "c"."ts" between cast(? as timestamp) 
                            and cast(? as timestamp))
         order by "c"."ts" asc 
         limit ? offset ?
       ) as "xmin"
  , lateral 
       ( select min("c"."ts") as "max_ts", "c"."id" as "max_id", "c"."transaction_id" as "max_trans_id" 
         from "public"."machine_economy_counters" as "c" 
         where ("c"."move_event_id" = "g"."id" 
           and "c"."ts" between cast(? as timestamp) 
                            and cast(? as timestamp)) 
         order by "c"."ts" desc 
         limit ? offset ?
       ) as "xmax" 
where "xmin"."min_ts" is not null
```

As far as I can see this SQL looks very much like the one posted above which works when run directly on the PostgreSQL 9.3.3 server.

### The Question

My SQL statement does not contain a GROUP BY, so why does the PostgreSQL driver state that I need this?

Am I doing something wrong in the JOOQ statement?

### Extra info

- PostgreSQL driver version: 9.3-1101-jdbc41
- JOOQ version: 3.3.0
- Java version: 1.7

Comment: The two are not the same. The second one uses `min("c"."ts")` which is an aggregate function. And because there are other columns in the select list, a `group by` is required. The first statement only uses `c.ts` (without an aggregate). So the question is: why does JOOQ think it needs a `min()`?

Comment: You nailed it. My JOOQ code had a ``min()`` to much when creating the ``min_ts`` field. Please add an answer if you like.

Comment: @uldall: Nice usage of `LATERAL` with jOOQ. How does using medium-complex SQL with jOOQ work out for you?

Comment: @LukasEder First of all great piece of software! It is very nice how you can type the sub selects first and then use them easily in outer selects. Makes the statements more readable than with normal SQL. The JOOQ documentation is a bit sparse on how to create large statements as the one above. Is my approach the correct one?

Comment: Thanks. Good point. [We'll add an example to the manual](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3137). There are various approaches. Yours makes perfect sense (to me). But it's always good to  see how users actually use an API